# FileLoadException troubleshooting

Tags: .net

I using System.Xaml to serialize workflows and I'm getting the following exception from within my test classes coming from the System.Xaml.dll assembly. It's odd since this has been working before and it's suddenly stopped working. I'm guessing that I might have installed some new assemblies that are causing the conflict.  My question is how can I figure out which assembly was attempted to be loaded, and what version was expected when it was to be loaded. I'm guessing that Microsoft.Activities is referencing an incorrect version of System.Workflow.Activities but I don't know which one it needs.

System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Activities, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

at System.Signature.GetSignature(Void* pCorSig, Int32 cCorSig, RuntimeFieldHandleInternal fieldHandle, IRuntimeMethodInfo methodHandle, RuntimeType declaringType)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.get_Signature()
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.GetParametersNoCopy()
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetIndexParametersNoCopy()
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetIndexParameters()
   at System.Xaml.Schema.TypeReflector.FilterProperties(PropertyInfo[] propList, List`1 knownMembers, Boolean skipKnownNegatives)
   at System.Xaml.Schema.TypeReflector.LookupAllMembers(ref ICollection`1 newProperties, ref ICollection`1 newEvents, ref List`1 knownMembers)
   at System.Xaml.XamlType.LookupAllMembers()
   at System.Xaml.XamlType.GetAllMembers()
   at System.Xaml.XamlObjectReader.ObjectMarkupInfo.GetXamlSerializableProperties(XamlType type, SerializerContext context)
   at System.Xaml.XamlObjectReader.ObjectMarkupInfo.AddRecordMembers(Object value, SerializerContext context, ParameterInfo[] methodParameters, XamlType xamlType)
   at System.Xaml.XamlObjectReader.ObjectMarkupInfo.AddRecordMembers(Object value, SerializerContext context, TypeConverter converter)
   at System.Xaml.XamlObjectReader.ObjectMarkupInfo.ForObjectInternal(Object value, SerializerContext context, TypeConverter converter)
   at System.Xaml.XamlObjectReader.ObjectMarkupInfo.ForObject(Object value, SerializerContext context, TypeConverter instanceConverter, Boolean isRoot)
   at System.Xaml.XamlObjectReader.MemberMarkupInfo.ForSequenceItems(Object sourceOrValue, XamlMember property, XamlType xamlType, SerializerContext context, Boolean allowReadOnly)
   at System.Xaml.XamlObjectReader.MemberMarkupInfo.ForSequence(Object source, XamlMember property, SerializerContext context, Boolean isAttachable)

continued for a long time...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem by downloading the latest version of the workflow manager. I think I updated Visual Studio 2012 without also updating this library.